# Possible combinations of digits

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

What is the probability that a random $r$-digit number $(r \geq 3)$ contains at least one
$0$, at least one $1$, and at least one $2$?

My initial guess was $1-(\frac{7}{10})^r$ seeing that it's $1$ minus the probability of neither $0$ nor $1$ nor $2$ appearing. But it's not the solution that appears in the textbook.

> Let $A$ be the event that the number selected contains at least one $0$. Let $B$ be the event that it contains at least one $1$ and $C$ be the event that it contains at least one $2$. The desired quantity is $P(ABC)=1-P(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c),$ where $$\begin{align}P(A^c\!\cup\! B^c\!\cup\! C^c) &= P(A^c)\!+\!P(B^c)\!+\!P(C^c)\!-\!P(A^cB^c)\!-\!P(A^cC^c)\!-\!P(B^cC^c)\!+\!P(A^cB^cC^c)\\ &= \frac{9^r}{9\times 10^{r-1}}+\frac{8\times 9^{r-1}}{9\times 10^{r-1}}+\frac{8\times 9^{r-1}}{9\times 10^{r-1}}-\frac{8^r}{9\times 10^{r-1}}-\frac{8^r}{9\times 10^{r-1}}\end{align}\\-\frac{7\times 8^{r-1}}{9\times 10^{r-1}}+\frac{7^r}{9\times 10^{r-1}}.$$

How can we arrive at the same answer?

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion counting reflects a nonzero leading digit, so *r-digit* has the sense here of the r'th digit having 1-9 as possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial guess would be correct (aside from the leading 0 issue) if the question was about the odds that a number contains at least a 0, 1 or 2. The real question however is at least one 0 *AND* at least one 1 *AND* at least one 2.

The explanation is the textbook way of calculating probabilities of non-independent events.

Answer (score 0):

Rather, it should be $1$ minus the probability of at least one of $0,1,2$ not appearing. It is *not* $1$ minus the probability that none of them appears. For example, $124$ has a $1$ and a $2$ appearing, but not a $0,$ so fails to qualify. Also, as hardmath points out, the leading digit *can't* be a $0,$ which is why the probability that neither $0$ nor $1$ nor $2$ appears in an $r$-digit number is $\dfrac{7^r}{9\times 10^{r-1}},$ rather than $\dfrac{7^r}{10^r}.$ Similarly, the three fractions with the "mixed" numerators are the result of needing to prevent a leading $0$--we don't need to do this to all of them, since the other $4$ fractions are probabilities of cases where there are no $0$s *at all*, so we don't need to adjust to prevent a leading $0$.

Ultimately, this is just an exercise of the inclusion-exclusion principle. If we just did $P(A^c)+P(B^c)+P(C^c),$ then we would have included the probability of numbers like $7432,7431,7430$ twice in the sum, and included the probability of numbers like $7543$ three times. Subtracting $P(A^cB^c),P(A^cC^c),P(B^cC^c)$ takes care of the overcounting for numbers like $7432,7431,7430$, but now the probability of numbers like $7543$ isn't included, so finally, we must add $P(A^cB^cC^c)$ back in. That's the idea behind the formula $$P(A^c\!\cup\! B^c\!\cup\! C^c) = P(A^c)\!+\!P(B^c)\!+\!P(C^c)\!-\!P(A^cB^c)\!-\!P(A^cC^c)\!-\!P(B^cC^c)\!+\!P(A^cB^cC^c)$$